# Excel 2016 - Calculation Speed

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have recently switched to a new laptop and installed Office 2016. My Excel calculates slowly and eats up all my resources.  The same spreadsheet on an older machine with Excel 2013 recalculates quickly.
As a reference my laptop had 16GB of RAM, intel 8th generation, 6 cores/12 threads. When I monitor the CPU is running with all 12 cores at 100% @ 3.5GHZ. I run Windows 10 professional and use a NVme SSD (samsung 970 pro).
It seems that every new version of Excel things slow down. The same was true when I 'upgraded' from Excel 2010 to Excel 2013.
Has anyone experienced the same problem or any suggestions?

Comment: See [Excel performance: Improving calculation performance](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/excel-performance/excel-improving-calcuation-performance).

Comment: Thank  you for providing the link.  I am familiar with these tips and tricks.  The problem is when I recalculate the sheets individually using VBA (selection.calculate) the recalc happens very fast.  When I use F9 the recalc after 2 hours with my laptop is at 3%. It seems that the problem is linked to the algorithm that Excel uses to determine the order of recalculation.